# ManyToManyField.add has no effect

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models, one of which (`Bar`) has two M2M relations pointing to `Foo`.

```
class Foo(Model):
    pass  # Whatever

class Bar(Model):
    foos = ManyToManyField(
        Foo, blank=True, related_name="+")
    bazs = ManyToManyField(
        Foo, blank=True, related_name="+")
```

After setting up a project using Django 1.8, none of these fields have working `.add()` methods, as demonstated below.

```
In [1]: foo = Foo.objects.first()
Out[2]: <Foo: ...>

In [3]: bar = Bar.objects.first()
Out[4]: <Bar: ...>

In [8]: bar.foos.add(foo)

In [9]: bar.foos.all()
Out[9]: []

In [11]: bar.save()

In [12]: bar.foos.all()
Out[12]: []
```

The documentation for `ManyToManyField` is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield).

The documentation for `related_name` is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). 
It is used because the reverse related_names for `Bar` would otherwise conflict on `Foo`.

What is the suggested workaround?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `related_name` ? Use different for every field.

Comment: @Gocht Yeah I've tried that. That creates backward relations from Foo to Bar, which is not what we/I want in this case.

Comment: One thing you need to keep in mind when adding objects to a M2M field is that the added object (foo in this case) must be previously saved, is it?

Comment: Yes, they are all in the database. (in that mocked ipython shell, they were all retrieved using `.first()`)

Comment: Where do the `Fields.` come from?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with those models in Django 1.8.5. Can you post the actual code (or an example that does recreate the problem).

Comment: @thebjorn I assume Fields is a typo because it's not a real example, and it should be `models.ManyToManyField`.

Comment: Oops let me edit that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Gocht that it most likely has something to do with the related_name attributes having the same value. Based on your comment it seems you are looking for the ForeignKey field rather than the ManyToManyField. If you only want a 1 way relationship from Bar to Foo that would be the best choice.

Was there another reason you didn't use that type of field?

Not enough points to comment on your comment otherwise I would put this there. :(

Comment: Yeah, multiple `Bar`s need to point to multiple `Foo`s, so `ForeignKey`s limit the option to M:1.